# Bubbling Events to Parent in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, events, event-handling

I have say this hierarchy in ASP.NET:

```
page
  user control 1
     user control 2
         control 3
```

What I want to be able to do is that when control 3 (it could be any kind of control, I want to do this generically) has the user do something with it that triggers a postback, it bubbles up some event to user control 2, or maybe even user control 1 (though I could have UC 2 manually bubble the event too).

Again, I want to do this generically, so that the hierarchy can change and it still works.  Maybe there are multiple controls (control 4, etc.) or a data bound control.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Event Bubbling is built into asp.net

Check this out:  https://web.archive.org/web/20210324143926/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051105-1.aspx

Basically, to raise the event that you want bubbled up:

```
RaiseBubbleEvent(this, args);
```

And then to catch it:

```
protected override bool OnBubbleEvent(object source, EventArgs e) {
    bool handled = false;

    if (e is TemplatedListCommandEventArgs) {
        TemplatedListCommandEventArgs ce = (TemplatedListCommandEventArgs)e;

        OnItemCommand(ce);
        handled = true;
    }
    return handled;
}
```

As the code implies, if this method returns false, the event will continue to bubble up the control hierarchy

> The implementation of RaiseBubbleEvent
>   is provided by Control and cannot be
>   overridden. RaiseBubbleEvent sends the
>   event data up the hierarchy to the
>   control's parent. To handle or to
>   raise the bubbled event, a control
>   must override the OnBubbleEvent
>   method.

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719644(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: OK, so if the command is a button, will the click of the button automatically bubble up to the user controls, or do I have to explicitly invoke the bubbling.  I think controls explicitly have to bubble up events by calling RaiseBubbleEvent, and that controls may not necessarily do this on their own.  Correct?  It's not like silverlight where tunnelling and bubbling naturally happen.

Comment: Yes, it's not like Silverlight; you have to manually raise the bubble event.  But once you do, it'll keep going until you return true from the `OnBubbleEvent` method.