# Find Usercontrol's Dropdownlist selected value on Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a User Control named **UCCountry.ascx**, this user control only has one dropdownlist of country. The name of my Page is **MyFirstPage.aspx**, on this page I have a repeater that binds the data based on the **CountryId** i.e **MyfirstPage.aspx** contains the Usercontrol.
Now I want to know how I can bind the data when a user changes the country using the **dropdownlist** in the Usercontrol.

Note: Which page life cycle event can I use to get the value of the dropdownlist and on which event do I need to bind the repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution own:
I have created two member variable:

```
/// <summary>
/// The name of the country selection dropdown list in the common header.
/// </summary>
public const string CountryDropDownName = "ucControl1$ddlCountry";

/// <summary>
/// The name of the PostBack event target field in a posted form.  You can use this to  see which
/// control triggered a PostBack:  Request.Form[PostBackEventTarget] .
/// </summary>
public const string PostBackEventTarget = "__EVENTTARGET";
```

Now override InitializeCulture on aspx page.

```
/// <SUMMARY>
/// Overriding the InitializeCulture method to set the user selected
/// option in the current thread. Note that this method is called much
/// earlier in the Page lifecycle and we don't have access to any controls
/// in this stage, so have to use Form collection.
/// </SUMMARY>
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    ///<remarks><REMARKS>
    ///Check if PostBack occured. Cannot use IsPostBack in this method
    ///as this property is not set yet.
    ///</remarks>
    if (Request[PostBackEventTarget] != null)
    {
        string controlID = Request[PostBackEventTarget];

        if (controlID.Equals(CountryDropDownName))
        {
            string selectedValue =
                   Request.Form[Request[PostBackEventTarget]];

           **//Bind your control here based on the countryID.**
        }
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to expose the DropDownList as public in your control.  That way your page can listen for events and respond to them.  Eg:

UCCountry.ascx

```
<asp:DropDownList Id="CountryDropDown" ... />
```

UCCountry.ascx.cs

```
public DropDownList CountryDropDown { get; protected set; }
```

MyFirstPage.aspx

```
<ctl:UCCountry Id="CountryControl" ... />
```

MyFirstPage.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CountryControl.CountryDropDown.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(CountryDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

protected void CountryList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do your databinding here
}
```

Comment: This is not possible to got the value via Pagelife cycle events?

Comment: Yes, you will use `Page_Load` and `CountryList_SelectedIndexChanged`.  But the bigger issue you face is access.  By default the controls within a User Control are protected and inaccessible to the parent Page.  To access them from the page, you must expose them.  Once they are exposed, you can then access them via the usual page lifecycle events.  You can also access a User Control's child controls from control lifecycle events, eg `Control_Load`, etc, but you won't have access to the page's repeater from within the control.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need `OnSelectedIndexChanged` even for the DropDownList.

```
protected void countriesDropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uCCountry.CountryId = countriesDropDownList.SelectedValue;
    uCCountry.DataBind(); // if necessary. 
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Homan:I want to rebind the Repeater which placed on the Page not in the usercontrol, when user change the index of dropdownlist(which placed in user control) I want to rebind the repeater based on the selected index of dropdownlist.

Comment: @Vijjendra: Actually I haven't used the Repeater before, but I think you can bind it in a similar way and that depend on how would you want to bind a country with an item in the repeater.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to bubble an event from the user control to the parent page. [Here is a question regarding this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423713/bubbling-events-to-parent-in-asp-net), and [an article that explains how to do it](http://odetocode.com/code/94.aspx).

The basic idea is that in the selected index changed event handler in your user control you fire off an event that the parent page subscribes to. In event handler in your page you can rebind your repeater.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of the DDL.  You will be able to get the selected value when that event fires.  You will need to make sure that `AutoPostBack="True"` on the DDL as well.  From there you can call the databinding in the event handler.

Comment: I did read it from the Event handler you can get the selected value and call your data bind command, as well as any methods to fill a datasource.

Comment: Ahh you want something like [This](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/08/23/raise-event-from-user-control-to-main-page-event-delegation-from-user-control-to-aspx-page-in-aspnetc/):