# how to add an event property to a user control ascx accessible to the host page as a string in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ascx control SomeCustomControl, which contains a button. If I want to expose the button's OnClick event so that the host page can trigger this button's OnClick, how do I add the event to the user control as a property so that the host page can assign the event to a handler name (eg. OnClick="EventName")?

host page aspx:

`<customcontrol:SomeCustomControl runat="server" ID="myCustomControl" OnClick="EventName">`

host page code behind:

`protected void EventName(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the link below. I think it is quite near to yours. or you can search for event bubbling.

[Bubbling Events to Parent in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423713/bubbling-events-to-parent-in-asp-net)

Download sample code from here. It has two user controls and one aspx page with event bubbling implmentation

https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=7A1FCBEC2CC6F643&resid=7A1FCBEC2CC6F643%212034&authkey=AANtP8lOxmwRJcQ